# How to implement sum of a field query in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

How can we implement the Hibernate sqlprojection in my query?

Here is my query

```
SELECT sum(total_amount) as total,created_at from order where created_at < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and doctor_id = 193 GROUP BY created_at
```

I have implement `DATE_SUB` function using `sqlRestriction` like this:

```
String sqlWhere = "created_at > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL "+activityGraph+" DAY) AND doctor_id = "+id +" GROUP BY created_at";
Criteria criteria = Hibernatesession.createCriteria(Order.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(sqlWhere));
```

But I don't know how I get the sum of a field using Hibernate query.

I found out that `setProjection` in Hibernate is used to get the sum as we desired but I don't know how to use it. Also here I want to use `sqlRestriction` to write WHERE condition for `date_sub` function.
So I will use `setProjection` and `sqlRestriction` in a single query.

Answer (score 3):

You're making you life difficult. Why don't you simply compute the date limit in Java before executing the query?

```
Date today = DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), Calendar.DATE);
Date limit = DateUtils.addDays(today, -7);
```

And since the query is completely static, why using the Criteria API. HQL is much easier:

```
String hql = "SELECT sum(o.totalAmount) as total, o.createdAt from Order o"
             + " where o.createdAt < :limit"
             + " and o.doctor.id = 193"
             + " group by o.createdAt";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
criteria.setProjection((Projections.sum("/* name of the mapping variable for total_amount*/")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getSum() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.sum("productCount"));
    List list = criteria.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return (int) list.get(0);
}
```

//hibernate mpping

```
<property name="productCount" type="int" column="PRODUCT_COUNT"/>
```